# Como trabalhar com Jquery Mobile collapsible e Ajax Síncrono?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Senhores, tenho um [collapsible](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/collapsible-dynamic/) que quando clicado chama um Ajax sincrono e exibi os resultados dentro dele. Estou tendo fazer com que quando ele for clicado exiba esse [gif](http://loadinggif.com/images/image-selection/27.gif) enquanto não recebe a resposta do Ajax. O problema é que como ele está síncrono o collapsible não abre enquanto a função não chegar ao fim, mesmo se eu usar a função `collapsible( "expand" )`.

Veja o código:

```
<div id="expansor" data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">

            <h4 id="expansorTitle">Teste.</h4>

            <input id="imgCarregando" type="image" src="img/carregando.gif" />
            <div id="resultadoAjax"></div>
        </div>

$(function() {

      $("#expansorTitle").click(
            //Meu Ajax síncrono     
      });

});
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Poste seu código

Comment: Beleza, estou editando a pergunta.